# How to use recursive with dates in Teradata?

Tags: teradata

I have the following table for people running a marathon

```
person  start       end
mike    2-Jun-14    2-Jul-14
nike    3-Jul-14    9-Aug-14
mini    1-Aug-14    3-Sep-14
sara    25-Jun-14   27-Jun-14
steve   12-Jun-14   3-Jul-14
stan    2-Jun-14    2-Aug-14
pete    3-Jul-14    9-Aug-14
tara    5-Jul-14    5-Sep-14
```

I need to create a table that shows if a person was in the process of running at the beginning of every month

- *On Jul 1, 2014* there were 3 people running the marathon: mike,
  steve, stan
- *On Aug 1,2014* there were 5 people: nike, mini, stan,
  pete,tara
- *On Sep 1,2014* there were 2 people: mini, tara
- etc . .

**The desired table should look like this**

```
person  running on
mike    1-Jul-14
nike    1-Aug-14
mini    1-Aug-14
mini    1-Sep-14
steve   1-Jul-14
stan    1-Jul-14
stan    1-Aug-14
pete    1-Aug-14
tara    1-Aug-14
tara    1-Sep-14
```

---

Right now, to do this I am running a separate query for each month. **This is very tedious**   I suspect that i should be using`recursive`, but I do not know how to implement it here.

*PS: I have Teradata 14 with all functions, except I cannot write my own `udf`s and `procedures`. How can I get the final table using Teradata sql ?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for recursion or a procedure, this is done using some proprietary Teradata SQL extension:

```
SELECT person, BEGIN(pd)
FROM vt
EXPAND ON PERIOD(start, end) AS pd BY ANCHOR MONTH_BEGIN
```

Comment: Yeah..he is a saviour!!